# Cobol write form-feed char to file

Tags: cobol

I have file defined

```
           select bankd-file assign to f-bankd-file
              file status is wx-fstat
              organization line sequential.
   fd  bankd-file.
  ****************
   01  bankd-rec                pic x(80).
```

And I am writing to this file line by line, just simple with write command. And on one line I need also write form-feed character. This character I have defined as

```
01 w-ff pic x value x'0C'.
```

But in output file, I have before form-feed char NUL char. Please how can I get rid of this NUL char? Other chars are written without any problems.
[image]

Comment: Could you trim that image, please? Have you looked at ADVANCING on WRITE in your documentation? Look at the description of a "line sequential" file. You can't write "non-text" data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not specify the used COBOL compiler therefore we can only guess. Different compilers include a `x'00'` before "non-text-data" to make sure it can be read in correctly (this is mainly done if someone tries to write a `COMP` item which may contain line breaks and/or form feeds).

This *may* not be possible with your compiler but normally you would do:

```
WRITE bankd-rec FROM SPACES BEFORE ADVANCING PAGE
```

(no need for the `FROM SPACES` when you do this `BEFORE`/`AFTER` the record you actually want to have the form-feed in)

Answer (score 0):

For Micro Focus COBOL, you can turn off x"00" before non-test-data by using the [INSERTNULL=OFF](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.enterprisedeveloper.vs2013%2FHRFLRHEXFH1A.html&resultof=%22%49%4E%53%45%52%54%4E%55%4C%4C%22%20%22%69%6E%73%65%72%74%6E%75%6C%6C%22%20) in the extfh.cfg